# Groups - abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite commutative group with an order of $pq$ where $gcd(p,q)=1$. If $G$ contains an element $a$ with an order of $p$, and an element $b$ with an order of $q$, show that $G$ is cyclic.

Well the only thing I know is that if the order of $G$ is prime then $G$ is cyclic

Can someone help me ?

Comment: "Associative group"...as opposed to "non-associative group"? What this last would be, anyway?

Comment: I strongly suspect that instead of "associative" you want to say "commutative" (equivalently, "abelian"). Your statement isn't true for non-abelian groups anyway, as witnessed by the symmetric group $S_3$ which has order $2\cdot3$, has elements of orders $2$ and $3$, but is not cyclic.

Comment: Also, this statement is false: "$G$ is cyclic only if the order of $G$ is a prime". A counterexample to that is the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ of order $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. Show that $ab$ generates $G$, i.e., that $o(ab) = pq$.